# Apache (on Ubuntu) spawns large number of tasks over time. Why & should/how I fix it?

Tags: apache, performance, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, load

I have about 4-6 files (per user), mostly static ones being requested from an AWS instance. Peak traffic is about 1K visitors at a time (via Google Analytics Real Time).

The instance is powerful enough and it rarely peaks at 100% CPU, has free RAM. mpm_prefork is adjusted for 1480 simultaneous connections. After restarting Apache2, there are around 200 processes running during peaks.

However, **over a couple of days the amount of processes seems to swell up** and requires me to restart apache in order to negate the timeout errors for users.

Am I missing anything? Is this expected?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `MaxSpareServers` directive to something very low like 10 or 20. When instances are not needed anymore (not serving anything or in a keep-alive state), you should only get 10 or 20 idle workers.

If the workers number remains the same even when serving no client, then you've got some problem. Check your keep-alive timeout setting, or disable keep-alive altogether and see it has some effect. I've notice keep-alive is sometimes counterproductive, especially in busy environments.